# How to input text in alerts using protractor?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, protractor

I'm accessing a page that has an alert which asks for login credentials. I've looked online and all i searched is, how to switch to the alert box. How do I input the username and password?

I've tried automating this page before using `Selenium WebDriver` / `java` but I used the `Robot` class to input the values as I can't access the Alert box using the `switchTo()` method of webdriver.

So my question is how can we access this using protractor and if that's not possible, is there a way to use something similar to the Robot class? Sorry i'm a newbie with `JS`.

Comment: i didnt understand why using the Robot class. to swith to the pop-up it has to be an iframe, else you can access it directly..

Comment: it's not in an iframe..it's an alert, which is not part of the DOM, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url needs http basic authentication credentials then you can handle it better by passing it in the url instead of trying to fill it from alerts

Your url in 'browser.get()' should be like this

'Http ://username:password@myapp.com'

PS: pls ignore any typos. Replied from phone

Comment: I tried this before but my problem before was that I didn't escape the slashes in my username.. so now that I have, it worked. Thanks! This doesn't really answer the question but it's a good work around and I'll accept it.

Comment: as a note this will not work in the future for many browser.  Chrome 57 already doesn't support it.